# Mean Curvature for a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I do not understand the following and would be very appreciative of some guidance.

The sum of principal curvatures $\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$ can be expressed as $\left(\frac{y_{x}}{x(1+y_x^2)^\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y_{xx}}{(1+y_x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ for an axisymmetric surface (https://youtu.be/uxsRW4KofUc?t=1471).

How does this work for a sphere? Say $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$. The principal curvatures should be everywhere equal. Consider only $\frac{1}{R_1}$. In the first quadrant, $y_x$ is negative, while in the 4th quadrant it is positive. This implies $R_1$ is not constant. A similar story can be said for the second principal curvature. How is this possible? And what about when $x = 0$, one plane of curvature cannot disappear!

Thanks for your time and apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: What is $y$ in your expression of the sum of prcincipal curvatures?

Comment: Say precisely what you mean by an axisymmetric surface. Why does this apply to a sphere?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I have no formal training in mathematics beyond entry level engineering courses. A sphere is axisymmetric because it is symmetric about an axis (In my head I think about this as being a surface of revolution). I do not see why the derived equation doesn't capture this. Ok, we could only consider the first two quadrants and assert the other two are the same due to axisymmetry, but why doesn't the equation do this anyway?.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am considering a circle, x^2 + y^2 = R^2 (or a sphere if in 3D).